# How to customize sphinx search?

Tags: full-text-search, python-sphinx

I wanted to be able to customize my python sphinx search to include keywords. For example, if I type `METHOD fill` it would prioritize (or ideally only show) methods with the word `fill` in it.

However, I couldn't find any functionality to do that, other than the `html_search_scorer`. Even in that, I couldn't find any documentation on how to write one, or the valid keys one could use in it.
I would appreciate any pointers to documentation pages.